# 404 error page not working in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

My Magento 2 404 page is not showing.
When incorrect URL.is called in my site ..it should redirect to 404 error page. instead, it's showing processing error and mail not sent

U can recreate error at [dentbay.com/gdndk](https://www.dentbay.com/gdnd/?SID=lj94qvgnieq0hqil77iosfi8t6)

here are log files

> a:4:{i:0;s:21:"Unable to send mail. ";i:1;s:11016:"#0 /home/dentbaydemolocat/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport->sendMessage()

Answer (score 0):

First of all please make sure that you have created **404 Not Found** CMS page.

After that go to below location.

> Store > Configuration > General > Web > Default Page

Select "404 Not Found" CMS page in **CMS No Route Page** dropdowm.

Clear your cache and you are all set.

Comment: dear sir its already set..it was working fine until 2 days back when i have installed smtp and removed it.

Comment: Then this is something SMTP error. Please make sure that all the data related with SMTP module removed from Database. Like table and config values

Comment: a:4:{i:0;s:21:"Unable to send mail. ";i:1;s:11016:"#0 /home/dentbaydemolocat/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\Mail\Transport->sendMessage()

Comment: this is error log..can i get where to remove this smtp.

Comment: how did you remove that module? I mean SMTP?

Comment: i am sorry the smtp module was not installed properly and the backup was resorted.so it should not be becasue of that..

Comment: i have a question how come the 404 page error is calling for sending mail